# Celery task doesn't work when run inside docker container

Tags: docker, redis, celery

I recently installed celery and redis and it works fine. Then I tried the same method to install celery and redis inside the docker container(selenium/standalone-chrome), it doesn't execute the task.

The image shows as below :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpJ9m.png)

And it doesn't show the "[INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0....", so I don't know celery connect to redis or not.

tasks.py :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from celery import Celery
app = Celery(
   'tasks',
   broker='redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0',
   backend='redis://127.0.0.1:6379/1',
)
@app.task
   def hello():
   print('Hello')
```

Comment: please add any configuration files or command-line instructions you've used in this use case that might affect the workflow to the original question, for example `docker` instructions, `docker-compose` files, environment variables, etc`

Comment: I can tell you that Redis probably isn't on 127.0.0.1 -- the Celery container thinks the localhost address is the Celery container, not the Redis container -- but I'm not sure what the right address would be, or why it would write out a PNG file.  Have you read background material like [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) that discusses communication between containers?

Comment: @NoamYizraeli thanks for reply.
I don't have the docker-compose file. I just pull the image from docker hub(docker pull selenium/standalone-chrome) then start with "docker run -d -p 4444:4444 -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm selenium/standalone-chrome".

Comment: As mentioned by David maze, when referring to the local address the container assumes its own address which doesn't fly because it's not it but itself running all those services but other containers, if you'd run the containers under the same docker network with the bridge driver preferably you'd be able to connect to the redis service by listing the redis hostname (or how you called the redis service)

Answer (score 0):

I create the docker-compose.yml , run the container and edit tasks.py.

docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '3'
services:
 selenium:
  image: 'selenium/standalone-chrome'
  restart: unless-stopped
  ports:
        - '4444:4444'
```

tasks.py :

```
app = Celery(
  'tasks',
  broker='redis://localhost:6379/0',
  backend='redis://localhost:6379/1',
)
```